# Regex for multiple search & replace Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

Please help me in the following pattern

Current text

```
ALPHA;111,'BI_209'
ALPHA;222,'BI_213'
ALPHA;AAA,'BI_209'
ALPHA;FFF,'BI_209'
ALPHA;123,'BI_220'
```

Intended status after first round of find & replace in Notepad ++

```
BI_209;111,'BI_209'
ALPHA;222,'BI_213'
BI_209;AAA,'BI_209'
BI_209;FFF,'BI_209'
ALPHA;123,'BI_220'
```

As seen above, in the first round - I intend to search a specific pattern `* ALPHA* BI_209*`  and replace with `*BI_209*BI_209*`.
Please help me with the correct regex in FIND as as well as REPLACE fields to achieve what I plan to get. Note there a varying texts like  ';111,'    .....  ';222,'  .... ';AAA,' in between which shouldn't get changed or affected.

If I get a pattern for find & replace, it would be help in a second (and further) round(s) of  multiple find & replace - to achieve this output

```
BI_209;111,'BI_209'
BI_213;222,'BI_213'
BI_209;AAA,'BI_209'
BI_209;FFF,'BI_209'
BI_220;123,'BI_220'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find what: `ALPHA(.*'BI_209')`

   Replace with: `BI_209\1`

   Explanation: what is matched by the regex between the parentheses gets saved, and can be recalled with `\1`. Parentheses can define multiple capture groups e.g. `(ALPHA)(.*)('BI_209')`, that can be reused with backreferences `\1`, `\2`, `\3` ...
2. Putting this all together, you could do all substitutions in one pass:

   Find what: `ALPHA(.*)'(BI_209|BI_213|BI_220)'`

   Replace with: `\2\1'\2'`

   Here, the `|` symbol specifies alternative strings to search for.
3. Here's a more general solution in case you later add different codes:

   Find what: `ALPHA(.*)'(BI_\d{3})'`

   Replace with: `\2\1'\2'`

   Here `\d` matches any digit, and is a synonym for `[0-9]`; `{3}` is the repetition factor; `\d{3}` matches any sequence of exactly three digits.

Note: since paretheses are special characters, if you want to specify a literal `(` or `)` you need to escape it with a backslash, like so: `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: I went step by step in order to better explain the available options. Máté Juhász's answer immediately solves your last point and is more general.

Comment: Awesome explanation. I used the logic you gave to do everything at one shot . i.e search for  (ALPHA)(.*)(BI_)(.*)(') and replace by \3\4\2\3\4\5

Comment: Great, I like the fact that you could use the information provided to elaborate your own solution.

Comment: Simlev - Couple of questions

Comment: Simlev - Couple of questions. 1)  - How to split when a bracket comes in way of text ..... example ->      ALPHA('Hello') . I tried to use (ALPHA(')(.*)(')) . The plan was to slit like this ALPHA('   ->1      Hello  ->2    '  ->3  .. it showed error. Is the only way to find the back references  like this (ALPHA)(.*)(')(.*)(')   meaning it splits ALPHA   ->1    (   -> 2   '  -> 3   Hello  ->4    '  ->5

Comment: I added a note in the answer on how to escape special characters. There's actually a lot to learn in order to master regular expressions, I did quite some reading on [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info) site when I started to use them. It seems you appreciated the answers you got, is there a reason you didn't accept any yet?

Comment: Thanks a lot on that escape part using \ .  I ll refer that site for that. 
Sorry I m unable to get what you exactly meant by ", is there a reason you didn't accept any yet? – simlev 3 mins ago"  I appreciate the answers and I m able to progress a lot in regex coz of the tips you gave.

Comment: I m unable to do something in multiline find and replace. I tried toolbucket plugin from https://github.com/phdesign/NppToolBucket/downloads . 
The issue I m facing is like this . I have a text like first line ->   ALPHA('Hello')    second line -> IGNORE111  Third line -> IGNORE222 Fourth line-> BETA('John')        ..... I want to replace Hello with Hi (first line) and John with Mary (Fourth line) . I dont want any replacement in second & third lines. 
Any idea on how to go about this? Your help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Oh wait, is there any accept button or like button to the answers I get ? I m new to superuser website - pls enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: Since you asked a question and received at least an answer, you are able to formally accept one of them to let others know that it solved your problem. [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :-)

Comment: Ok - saw that accept tick mark. Sorry about that. Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: Could you help me in that multiline issue. Few inroads would be great as I got 12000+ line ifc files (47 nos) to find and replace :)

Comment: Multiline regex replace is possibly not what you are looking for and is trickier. If I were you I'd stick to line-by-line whenever possible, e.g. by writing a regex that will not match the lines you mean to ignore: `(?!IGNORE)Hello` `Hi`.

Comment: Since comments are drifting away form the original topic, you should ask a new question with proper formatting and detailed description. This way you are going to attract more attention and get better answers. Multiple substitutions are more easily done with a scripting language.

Comment: Actually my question & intention wasnt properly articulated. Let me repharse my ques -> Imagine a text like first line -> ALPHA('Hello John') second line -> IGNORE111 Third line -> IGNORE222 Fourth line-> BETA('Hi Mary'). I want  Hi Mary (fourth line) to be replaced by Hello John. The actual content in teh fourth line between BETA('    and   ') should be replaced from the content fetched between ALPHA('    and   ') in first line.

Comment: Ok i ll post a new question

Answer (score 1):

To find a text `ALPHA...'BI_xxx'` and replace to `'BI_xxx'...'BI_xxx'`:

- open find and replace dialog
- check "regular expression"
- find what: `ALPHA(.*'(BI_\d+)')`
- replace to: `\2\1`
  test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/U0aRL5/2)

This will match any `'BI_xxx'`  where `xxx` is a number of at least one digit.

Comment: Worth my upvote, I didn't think of using nested capture groups. The inner set of `()` should be moved inside the `''` in order to provide the exact solution.